# PrintStream write(int i) method doesn't work?

Tags: java, io, system.out

I'm learning about I/O and the stream abstraction.
I came across this little toy example which should open a stream attached to a text file and display the content (simple ASCII text) to the default destination attached to System.out, the console..
It doesn't display a thing,where am I wrong?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    InputStream in=new FileInputStream("readme.my");
    while (true) {
        int byteRead=in.read();
        if (byteRead==-1) break;
        System.out.write(byteRead);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Try to add System.out.flush() at the end to flush the stream out. And close in as well, it's good coding practice.

Comment: @JPMoresmau yeah,flushing the stream works for me too.. I didn't know that PrintStream needs flushing ( I thought it was automatically flushed on program termination..). Closing the stream works as well, as it flushes the stream befor closing I think..

Answer (score 0):

The `System.out.write(byteRead); call writes a byte as-is (without doing any conversion) to the standard output stream for your application.  The output stream's character encoding depends on how you have configured your system.

- If you are reading from a binary file, there is a good chance that it contains no printable characters ... depending on the default character encoding.
- The file could be empty.

If you are trying to display as decimal bytes, then you should be using a `print` method; please the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for `PrintStream`.

---

It is also possible that the problem is that the `System.out` stream is not being flushed, and hence some data is not being output.  Try calling `flush()` after the loop exits.

(The `System.out` and/or `System.err` streams maybe configured to autoflush each time they see a newline.  However, if your input file contains no newlines, that won't happen.)

---

> ( I thought it was automatically flushed on program termination..).

It is not a good idea to rely on "I though that ...".  Check the javadocs.  In this case, the javadocs for `System.out` do not specify that this happens, so your assumption is beyond the "spec".

Comment: the file is plain 7-bit ASCII so it's made of byte representing printable characters by definition. I am simply copying those bytes (between 32 and 127) and sending them to the console where they should be displayed as text (the console interprets those numbers as characters, or so I have understood)